# Tomcat JSF Session BEan @Predestroy "Session already invalidated"

Tags: session, jsf, tomcat, tomcat7

So I try to access an attribute of my [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) on my `@PreDestroy` method on a `@SessionScoped` JSF managed bean using

```
session.getAttribute("myAttribute");
```

But I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session has already been invalidated
```

Why?

I need to access the list of connections to external services opened by that session before one of my session beans is destroyed, and they are of course stored on a session attribute object.

How can I do that?

Comment: Accessing session attributes in a session scoped JSF managed bean? Why not store them into a true session scoped managed bean instead?

Comment: what do you mean by "true"?

Comment: "true" means "true". A managed bean designated with a true `@SessionScoped` annotation.

Comment: Well it **is** a managed bean designated with a `@SessionScoped` annotation. What am I missing here? What do you mean by "true" `@SessionScoped` annotation? CDI? EJB? They are all part of the standard Java EE API.

Comment: I think @Tiny means that you should have the one with the lists injected instead of manually loading it from the session. For that it needs to be a ManagedBean (JSF, CDI, whatever) too. I **hope** the PreDestroy is called then in the order of 'Depending' and then Dependent so you can access it

Comment: Thatnks, I went that way. I still don't understand why session is invalidated before predestroy instead of right after...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly accessing a session attribute in a session scoped managed bean doesn't make sense. Just make that attribute a property of the session scoped managed bean itself.

```
@SessionScoped
public class YourSessionScopedBean implements Serializable {

    private Object yourAttribute; // It becomes a session attribute already.

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Just access yourAttribute directly, no need to do it the hard way.
    }

}
```

The exception you faced occurred because the session was explicitly invalidated via a [`HttpSession#invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) call instead of "just" expired.

Comment: That's what I did in the end, but that explicit call invalidating the session is weird. Does JSF do that? Because I am certain I am not doing it. I just let the session expire.